# 'runfile' is not defined in python 2.7 spyder 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

1. I opened my anaconda prompt and I got this message everytime without typing anything
2. I am using python 2.7 for some time but suddenly this error appeared today without updating anything
3. I had tried number of solutions but those did not work for me
   when I tried
   set SPYDER_DEBUG=2
   spyder --show-console I get
   'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
   'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\aditya royal\Anaconda2\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 5, in 
   sys.exit(spyder.app.start.main())
   File "C:\Users\aditya royal\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 104, in main
   mainwindow.main()
   File "C:\Users\aditya royal\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2955, in main
   or options.optimize)
   File "C:\Users\aditya royal\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\windows.py", line 33, in set_attached_console_visible
   return bool(ShowWindow(console_window_handle, flag[state]))
   KeyError: 3

I had tried solving my error by adding the path in my environment variable but I still see the error and I also tried stopping my firewall for sometime, I also tried spyder --reset, spyder --default and the problem still persists

Answer (score 1):

I had finally found an answer 
Recently I named a file csv.py, I deleted it and everything is fine now